# Break loop by synchronization primitive in C++11 threading

Tags: multithreading, mutex

Does anybody know how one can break the loop/thread in more conventional and efficient way than in example below?

```
#include <mutex>
#include <thread>

std::mutex m;
int cnt = 0;

void foo() {
  while(!m.try_lock()){
    ++cnt;
  }
}

int main() {
  m.lock();
  std::thread th(&foo);
  // Some other code...  
  m.unlock(); // Unlock m to break the loop.
  // Some other code...  
}
```

Advantages and disadvantages for the given example? Thx!

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I need one thread be able to break the loop in another thread Gracefully and Efficiently (in terms of modern C++), like it is already done in example above (the problem is I am not sure whether my example is graceful and efficient, there might be probably more cool way to do it).